# Live site not finding image file

Tags: django, apache

I currently have the function of uploading images on my site. All the images are working uploading correctly, but when I try to display them using the `image.url` attribute in the view, it gives me a 404 not found error.

My believe it might be something with my Apache config or Django settings.py.

In my Apache config under  I have:

```
Alias media/ /var/www/MySite/media/
<Directory /var/www/MySite/media>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

In my settings.py:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
```

In my view I am trying to display the image as follows:

```
{% for photo in photos %}
        <div class="col-md-3 photo-wrapper">
            <img src="{{ photo.image.url }}"/>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The image then looks for this url:

```
http://mysite.co.za/media/profile_photos/photo.png
```

But it doesn't find the image.

I did check that the image gets uploaded and it does to the correct location.

Also my model for clarification:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_photos')
```

Note: This is working fine when I work with the site on my localhost.

Edit:

So while I was trying different fixes I messed up some stuff that caused me to change the Debug in the settings.py to True, then I saw the image was actually being shown. I changed the debug to false again and the image was once again not showing. What would cause dubug to influence this?

Comment: what is the value of image.url? Is it actually http://mysite.co.za/media/profile_photos/photo.png?

Comment: yes, exactly as shown in the post, but it can't find that URL

Comment: If you have access to server, have you verified that the file actually exists there?

Comment: Who is the owner of `/media/` directory on server?

Comment: The owner is root, permissions are exactly the same as the static folder, which is working and set up the same as the media folder, and yes the images are actually uploading and are on the server.

Comment: @Riaan: Try chown `/media/` to your Apache user (`www-data` or whatever).

Comment: I did correct the permissions, check my edit for updates to what is happening now.

Answer (score 0):

The apache [alias directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) should start with a `/`

```
Alias /media/ /var/www/MySite/media/
```

Comment: I tried your fix but still did not work, also check my edit, some new stuff came up.

Comment: From your edit I can say that `DEBUG = True` enables correct (but insecure) routing, that's why image is shown. Try setting not only `Alias` to `/media/`, but  `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'` as well. This works for my projects.